# "Chorizo" como sinónimo de "ladrón"

Tags: etimología, definiciones, españa, sinónimos, caló

¿Por qué en España la palabra "chorizo" es coloquialmente usada para referirse a los ladrones?

Comment: Nunca había escuchado ese significado de chorizo, excelente pregunta. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Como otras muchas palabras vulgares que se usan en la península, "chorizo" para referirse a un ladrón viene del [caló](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_cal%C3%B3), la lengua de los gitanos en la Península Ibérica.

En este caso, la palabra del caló "[chori](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=chori)" siginifica "ladrón", y con idéntico significado se ha adoptado al castellano.

> **chori.** *(Del caló* chori, *ladrón).*
>   *1. m. vulg.* Ratero, ladronzuelo.

De esta palabra "chori", es muy probable que por su parecido a "[chorizo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=8zVTkmc%7C8zXCZBX)", se empezara a llamar también así a los ladrones.

> **chorizo<sup>2</sup>, za.** *(De* chori, *infl. en su forma por chorizo<sup>1</sup>).*
>
> *1. m. y f. vulg.* Ratero, descuidero, ladronzuelo.

Como apuntan en los comentarios, también se usa chorro (en el Río de la Plata) o [choro](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=UYZ71wjBb2x58utROEn) <strike>(Colombia)</strike> para lo mismo, con idéntico origen. El verbo "[chorar](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?type=3&val=chorar&val_aux=&origen=RAE)" significa "robar". También con origen en el caló, se usa vulgarmente "[mangar](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=i1NDSmcxU2x5fNuYVEu)" para "robar" y "mangui" para "ladrón", generalmente de poca monta. En España al menos, generalmente el uso de términos cuyo origen está en el caló no es solo coloquial, sino incluso vulgar. Actualmente, "chorizo" se asocia a menudo con respecto a ladrones de tipo económico (corrupción en las esferas pública y privada, blanqueo de dinero, evasión de capitales...).

Comment: Interesante. En lunfardo (*slang* rioplatense), el término es **chorro**, muy probablemente derivado de *chori*.

Comment: En Colombia uno de los términos coloquiales para ladrón es *choro*.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, sí, parece que viene del mismo sítio, según el [DRAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=UYZ71wjBb2x58utROEn).

Comment: Este pregunta y su respuesta me han resultado muy divertida. Hago este comentario tan sólo como una aportación de cultura general sobre la diferencia en el uso del lenguaje en los diferentes países. En México un significado muy común de la palabra "choro" es "un discurso largo, enredado y no del todo cierto o completamente falso". Decir que alguien es un "chorero" es decirle que es un hablador e incluso un mentiroso. Decir "me estás choreando" es decir "me estás tratando de engañar". Completamente distinto a la pregunta original, pero me pareció que a alguien le podría parecer interesante :)

Comment: @SegioRomero Totalmente de acuerdo contigo sobre el uso de "choro" y "chorear" en México.

Comment: @SergioRomero, pues si te descuidas tienen el mismo origen, no sería descabellado :D La idea al final es la misma al menos.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina ¿en que región se usa? nunca la he oído.

Comment: De hecho, sí vas al traductor de google y colocás a traducir ladón al idioma Hindi (Oficial de la India), te lo traduce a Chorr. Se dice que el idioma caló tiene su origen en La India.

Comment: Hay que aclarar que en Colombia "chorizo" se usa para designar un alimento de tipo embutido que se hace con carne de cerdo y cuya presentación es parecida a la salchicha.  
https://www.colombia.com/gastronomia/asi-sabe-colombia/entradas/sdi140/80752/chorizos-caseros-eje-cafetero

Comment: @alvalongo Sí, en España también. Por eso la pregunta, ya que es sorprendente que "ladrón" y "embutido" compartan palabra. Este doble sentido es lo que ha dado lugar a la mejor consigna de manifestaciones jamás creada: "No hay pan para tanto chorizo".